# Spring integration testing with jetty and websockets

Tags: java, spring, websocket, jetty, integration-testing

I have no problems doing Spring integration testing using Jetty without Websockets, using these annotations:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration( classes = { ApplicationConfig.class } )
@WebAppConfiguration
```

When I add Websockets into the Jetty, it is not possible to use this approach.

This repo shows that websocket integration tests work with Tomcat but not Jetty:

https://github.com/isopov/mockmvc-test-websocket

The issue seems to be because Spring's MockServletContext doesn't implement Jetty's ContextHandler.Context.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16263

The full discussion can be found here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7487

Apparently it is possible to Jetty websocket tests by starting Jetty rather than using mockmvc:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7487#issuecomment-375426956

How do you use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner without mockmvc?

James

Comment: Use a real server in your unit testing.  Jetty starts faster than the Spring mock server anyway.